# Is this normal behaviour for rails rendering a action specific css.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `results.css.erb` file which is in the searches view folder. My `searchescontroller#results` action looks like this.

```
...
  def results
  if params[:search_form] == "User search"
    @users = User.search(params[:name], params[:gender])
    render 'user_results' and return
  elsif params[:search_form] == "Post search"
    @posts = User.search(params[:name], params[:gender])
    render 'post_results'
  end
end
...
```

With the conditional in place I have to name my css.erb file `results.css.erb` otherwise rails gives a `rendering head :no_content` response for the css file.

But if I do this and add the `@users` variable to the css file rails complains about my `@users` variable in the css file, So;

if I remove the conditional and just have

```
def results
    @users = User.search(params[:name], params[:gender])
    render 'user_results'
  end
end
```

Rails will complain Actionview::MissingTemplate error so I have to change it from `results.css.erb` to the name of the render call ie `user_results.css.erb` then everything works. I would like to keep the conditional but.

How can I trouble shoot this?

I am getting the path from

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag(search_results_path(format: :css), media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload') %>
```

Comment: What is the complaint about the `@users` variable?

Comment: It says `undefined method 'each' for....` as I have `<% @users.each do |user| %>` and rails normally does this when it cant find the variable in teh first place it will carry on to the next method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what happens then u make request to results action with no params?
It will try call default render what is action name result.css.erb and u probably use @users variable in results.css.erb

Ff u dont wanna render default template u can redirect to other action or render some other action if parameters are not met but something has to be rendered in controller action. If u wanna just render empty content u can use something like render plain: ""

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just thought this that the conditional must not be ran through with the css.erb file, but I am not sure why.. I was actually thinking of trying a respond_to method before the conditional, ill give that a try.

Comment: Ok I figured it. Even though my stylesheet_link_tag call and code is all done server side you still need to add the params to the link tag for it to work with the method otherwise rails will default to as what @Imre is saying. So it should be `<%= stylesheet_link_tag(search_results_path(:search_form => "User search", format: :css), ...`